# Save Smart Blob in Informix Database and FluentNhibernate

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, blob, informix

I need to Save a Smart Blob  in informix database, ther is my model :

```
 public class ArtistaFoto : Entity
{
    public virtual Artista Artista { get; set; }
    public virtual int NumeroSeq { get; set; }
    public virtual byte[] BlobArtistas { get; set; }
    public virtual string NomeArquivos { get; set; }
    public virtual string Extensao { get; set; }
}
```

there is my Mapping

```
       public ArtistaFotosMapping()
    {
        this.Table("sb_aneartistas");
        this.CompositeId().KeyReference(x => x.Artista, "cdartista").KeyProperty(x => x.NumeroSeq, "nrseq");
        this.Map(x => x.BlobArtistas).Column("sbaneartistas");
        this.Map(x => x.NomeArquivos).Column("nome_arq");
        this.Map(x => x.Extensao).Column("extensao");
    }
```

and there is my exception when I try to save my entity

[image]

So I know that this field in Informix Database is a SmartBlob, and this is not a normal blob (byte or string).Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My difficulty is in build a connection follow :

```
   ISessionFactory factory = Fluently.Configure()
                          .Database(
                IfxSQLIConfiguration
               .Informix1000
              .ConnectionString("Provider=Ifxoledbc.2;Password=xxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxx;Data Source=xxxx")
                             .Driver<OleDbDriver>()
               .Dialect<InformixDialect1000>()
               .ShowSql())
               .Mappings(x => x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<ArtistaFotoMapping>()
               ).ExposeConfiguration(x =>
                  x.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.PrepareSql, "True")
               )
               .BuildSessionFactory();`
```

and I change for IfxOdbcConfiguration that follow sample:

```
  ISessionFactory factory = Fluently.Configure()
  .Database(
    IfxOdbcConfiguration
    .Informix1000
    .ConnectionString("DRIVER={IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER};SERVER=xxxx;DATABASE=xxxx;UID=xxx;PWD=xxx;NEEDODBCTYPESONLY=1;")
    .ShowSql())
    .Mappings(x => x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<ArtistaFotoMapping>()
    ).ExposeConfiguration(x =>
       x.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.PrepareSql, "False")
    )
    .BuildSessionFactory();
```